# How to plot a donut chart around a point on a scatterplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, donut-chart

I have a scatterplot with a few points which I can plot easily enough. I want to add a donut chart around each of the points to indicate which classes make up the point. I saw the example of [nested donut charts](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/nested_pie.html) but I want to make a scatter/donut plot for multiple points.

This is the code I have so far for making the scatterplot and the donut chart. It will plot all 3 data points and one donut chart for the first point.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

## Scatter
# create three data points with three random class makeups
N = 3
N_class = 5
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
vals = [np.random.randint(2, size=N_class) for _ in range(N)]

plt.scatter(x, y, s=500)
plt.show()

## Donut plot
# Create 5 equal sized wedges
size_of_groups = np.ones(5)

# Create a pieplot
plt.pie(size_of_groups, colors=["grey" if val == 0 else "red" for val in vals[0]])
#plt.show()

# add a circle at the center
my_circle=plt.Circle( (0,0), 0.7, color='white')
p = plt.gcf()
p.gca().add_artist(my_circle)

plt.show()
```

Something similar to this for each point (disregarding the pie chart center, just a scatter point)

[image: Desired output like this (disregarding the pie chart center for now, I've figured that)]

Comment: How should the final figure look like? Do you have any sample output?

Comment: So you need three donut charts plotted next to each other?

Comment: Each point gets its own donut chart around it. More of a question of how to combine the two plots/axes with the appropriate centering/sizing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adapting the [Scatter plot with pie chart markers example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_piecharts.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-piecharts-py), one can just add a white marker in the middle to make the pies become donuts.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# first define the ratios
r1 = 0.2       # 20%
r2 = r1 + 0.4  # 40%

# define some sizes of the scatter marker
sizes = np.array([60, 80, 120])*4
center_sizes = sizes/3.

# calculate the points of the first pie marker
#
# these are just the origin (0,0) +
# some points on a circle cos,sin
x = [0] + np.cos(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi * r1, 10)).tolist()
y = [0] + np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi * r1, 10)).tolist()
xy1 = np.column_stack([x, y])
s1 = np.abs(xy1).max()

x = [0] + np.cos(np.linspace(2 * np.pi * r1, 2 * np.pi * r2, 10)).tolist()
y = [0] + np.sin(np.linspace(2 * np.pi * r1, 2 * np.pi * r2, 10)).tolist()
xy2 = np.column_stack([x, y])
s2 = np.abs(xy2).max()

x = [0] + np.cos(np.linspace(2 * np.pi * r2, 2 * np.pi, 10)).tolist()
y = [0] + np.sin(np.linspace(2 * np.pi * r2, 2 * np.pi, 10)).tolist()
xy3 = np.column_stack([x, y])
s3 = np.abs(xy3).max()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(range(3), range(3), marker=xy1,
           s=s1 ** 2 * sizes, facecolor='indigo')
ax.scatter(range(3), range(3), marker=xy2,
           s=s2 ** 2 * sizes, facecolor='gold')
ax.scatter(range(3), range(3), marker=xy3,
           s=s3 ** 2 * sizes, facecolor='crimson')
# centers
ax.scatter(range(3), range(3), s=center_sizes, marker="o", color="w")
plt.show()
```

[image]

If instead a real `pie` chart is desired, you may use the arguments `center` and `radius` to position several pies on the axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# first define the ratios
r1 = 0.2       # 20%
r2 = r1 + 0.4  # 40%

x = list(range(3))
y = list(range(3))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for xi,yi in zip(x,y):
    ax.pie([r1,r2,r2], colors=['indigo', "gold", 'crimson'],
           center=(xi, yi), radius=0.2+xi/4, 
           wedgeprops=dict(width=(0.2+xi/4)/2), frame=True)
ax.autoscale()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I was trying to use `pie` objects and couldn't get it to work properly, doing the scatter is perfect as I want to replace the white center with something else so it'll use the same centers and I change sizes.